# Django form.is_valid() issue

Tags: python, django

The idea is a user will create a post on this page and fill out the title and content.
Once they submit this form, a Post instance will be created with the inputs of the user for title and content. This instance will also have the id of the user associated to it.

I've done a print test which yields the outputs I'm looking for but it appears that the form is not valid. Any thoughts?

```
#Resolved - Thank you all

    def post(self, request, locationname):
        form = PostCreate(request.POST)
        current_user = request.user
        found_location = Location.objects.get(name = locationname)

        if form.is_valid():
            
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.post_location = Location.objects.get(id = found_location.id)
            form.author = Profile.objects.get(user_id = current_user)
            form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)
```

```
#views.py 
class LocationDetail(View):

    def post(self, request, locationname):
        current_user = request.user 
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id = current_user)
        form = PostCreate() 
        found_location = Location.objects.get(name = locationname)
        context = {"found_location": found_location, "form": form}
        if request.method == "POST":
            post_author = user_profile.user_id 
            post_title = request.POST['title']
            post_content = request.POST['content']
            print(post_author)
            print(post_title)
            print(post_content)
            if form.is_valid():
                Post.objects.create(
                    title = post_title, 
                    content = post_content,
                    author_id = post_author,
                )
                form.save()
            return render(request,'location-detail.html', context)
```

```
#forms.py + models.py
class PostCreate(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post 
        fields = ['title', 'content']

class Profile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    profile_location = models.CharField(max_length = 80, blank=True, null=True)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Post(Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} - {self.title}'
```

```
#template: location-detail.html

<form action="" method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to check if the request is a "POST" request since you are using class-based views. The `post()` method will be called by the dispatcher method inside of the base "View" class when you submit the form. Before checking if the form is valid, fill the instance of the form with the request data, then you can set the "author" field like so:

```
def post(self, request, locationname):
    form = PostCreate(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
         
        # don't commit to database yet
        form = form.save(commit=False)

        # set author field
        form.author = user_profile.user_id
        
        # commit to database 
        form.save()

    return redirect("<url_name>")
```

When `.save(commit=False)` is called, the form instance with the data is saved without committing to the database. Then, when the `.save()` method is called the second time, the data will be saved to the database. It is recommended to redirect to the desired url after a POST request. The `<url_name>` comes from the url in your 'urls.py' file that you want to redirect to.

More info can be found in the django docs here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/

Comment: Hi Heath, thanks a bunch for your answer. I'm relatively new to Django, and coding as well. After some tweaking and further research I was able to resolve the problem and implement some additional features!

Answer (score 0):

Try to revise this line:

```
user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id = current_user)
```

to

```
user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id = current_user.id)
```

Since the argument user_id needs an id value, not an object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, this also helped with my solution!